# Laravel Exception Property [product_quantity] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance

Tags: php, laravel

I was trying to build an Ecommerce Website in Laravel and I got the Error saying
"Exception
Property [product_quantity] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance."
when I tried to update the product quantity in the database.

Basically, what I wanted to do is, If a user tries to add a product which is already there in their cart, the quantity gets incremented by 1 and the total product price gets changed accordingly. To achieve this, I first checked the DB for existing entry with

```
$findProduct = StoreCart::where('product_id', $product->id);
```

"StoreCart" is my model name to Store Cart Data. Then after the find query what i did was

```
if($findProduct) {
            // product is already in DB, set new quantity
            $newQuantity = $findProduct->product_quantity + $getQuantity;
            $newProductTotal = $findProduct->product_price * $newQuantity;
            // update the exsisting product
            $findProduct->update([
               'product_quantity' => $newQuantity,
               'product_total' => $newProductTotal,
            ]);

         } else {
            // create new field and store it in db
            StoreCart::create([
                'user_id' => Auth::id(),
                'product_id' => $product->id,
                'product_name' => $product->name,
                'product_price' => $amount,
                'product_quantity' => $getQuantity,
                'product_total' => $productTotal,
            ]);
        }
```

and when I tried to run this, the above error pops up saying [product_quantity] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.
Whats the issue with this?

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will change `$findProduct = StoreCart::where('product_id', $product->id);` to `$findProduct = StoreCart::where('product_id', $product->id)->first();` . It will work fine. According to your query output will be a collection of objects. you can't use update command to collection. You can use update comment to object.

Comment: sure, just waiting for the timer to run out, it won't let me mark so soon